# Styling lightning:combobox drop down to not hide inside modal and extend modal length?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-combobox

I am using the lightning:combobox standard component, and created a little UI that I then put in a modal window.

It looks fine except for this issue....

[image]

I the drop down hides inside the modal content area, and extends the length of the modal so there is a lot of white space beneath my buttons.

I want no white space beneath my buttons. I do not want the drop down menu to extend the length of anything.

Preferably I'd like it to just extend off of the modal, like how the blue highlight is. Does anyone know how to modify the CSS of the drop down to get such a thing to happen? I have been messing with the css a little bit, but so far nothing helped.

If that is not possible, is it possible to make its max height based on the modal so it doesn't extend out of view?

All it is is a basic

```
<lightning:combobox name="blah" options="{!v.myOptions}" aura:id="someId" label="some label" onchange="{!c.handleChange}" />
```

That gets instantiated inside a modal in another lightning component:

```
<div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aura:id="field-dependency-modal" class="slds-modal">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" onclick="{!c.closeEditor}"> 
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Close" />
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-arround_medium">
                <c:FieldDependencies someId="{!v.someId}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-backdrop" aura:id="field-dependency-modal-backdrop"></div>
```

is the component that contains the combobox.

So it has nothing more than the standard stylings it comes with so far.

Comment: Try setting the [overflow behavior](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) of the modal

Comment: Yeah, I think that will be necessary, but hiding the overflow of the modal content just hides the drop down behind it like it did before, but now I can't scroll the modal down to get to the bottom drop down values

Comment: Try setting it to visible, I would not recommend scroll or hidden. You may need !important as SF stylesheets are jerks some times.

Comment: Oh, it is normally set to visible. My issue with that is you then have extra space at the bottom of the modal. The drop down extends it past my buttons. I don't particularly like that. I want no extra space after my buttons. Not entirely sure it's possible, though.

Comment: In that case you'll probably have to do something like setting the position to relative and setting a high z index or something so that it's always on top and seperate from the normal flow. If relative doesn't work absolute should but that requires the parent element to have a non-default position attribute (set the parent to relative but don't re-position it at all) and it requires you to position your list manually.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to change to relative. I believe it has absolute position already by default. If changing to relative fails, I'll try messing with parent position and keep the drop down as absolute

Comment: If it already has absolute position it should be need a new z index...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ugh, I finally found the culprit. The drop down was absolute positioned, but applying a higher z-index was not doing anything.

It turns out it was the overflow options of the slds-modal__container. They had to be 'unset' completely.

So doing a

```
.THIS .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

on my lightning component solved it.

[image]

Comment: I just had this same issue on a modal in LWC. Your solution works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with LWC or Aura component only? I have the same issue ending up using simple html select option

Comment: This solution is from using it in an Aura component @ShinyaKoizumi. However, it may still hold true for doing this in LWCs? Not entirely sure. But LWCs don't let you override built in component CSS (like if you were using `lightning-select` or whatever it is and wanted to override that drop down part of it).

Comment: Oh man you just saved me a TON of time! thanks!

Comment: @TylerDahle you can just use the same css but without ".THIS". It worked great for my lwc component.

Comment: I'll add that for `slds-scrollable` behaviour is the same and dropdown is hiding under the end of the container. This answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately i have a dropdown inside `slds-scrollable` table and dropdown from the last  row is hiding under other div. I cannot remove overflow, because it won't be scrollable anymore. Any ideas? Z-index also doesn't work. @TylerDahle

Comment: I also have combo box inside scorllable but this solution not working for me in LWC
I have also started new thread on this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316179/combo-box-inside-slds-scrollable-doesnt-render-as-expected-in-lwc?noredirect=1#comment469832_316179 would highly appreciate if someone would provide a solution for this

Comment: @gs650x you may want to look into the shadow DOM of LWCs and how it restricts styling. Specifically you can't mess with baked in styling of standard components. This could be your issue.

Comment: so we cannot solve this in LWC?

Comment: If needing to manipulate a built in component (like `<lightning-something></lightning-something>`, no you cannot do a solution like this, the CSS for those cannot be overwritten.

You can try wrapping it in your own div, or go to slds components and copy the html there and build a custom modal/whatever the container is.

Comment: This solution will not work when you have scrollable content in the modal. if we add this style, if content size is increasing modal height will also increase and ends up with modal will go outside of screen. Any solution for this??

Answer (score 6):

For those wondering, this can work for LWC, as well. To bubble up from the comments as I just confirmed this works...

```
.THIS .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I wasn't able to override the CSS class, but succeeded by adding the style directly to the div: ```<div class="slds-modal__content " style="overflow: initial;">```

Comment: it does work for LWC but you don't need the `.THIS` and should be removed from your answer

Answer (score 5):

add `dropdown-alignment="auto"` attribute to lightning-combobox:

Example

```
    <lightning-combobox
    label="Cancel Reason"
    value={selectedValue}
    options={options}
    onchange={handleReasonChange}
    dropdown-alignment="auto">
```

Comment: Out of the solutions here, this is the change I found to work the best. For reference, it looks like adding this attribute to the component will force a calculated z-index, and fixed position onto the drop down. This is similar to how lightning-input-field does it within a lightning-record-edit-form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple solution by setting the `z-index`?

```
.THIS .slds-listbox {
    z-index: 9002; // I believe .slds-modal is 9001
}
```

Other solution could be to set a `min-height` of your modal-content div and a fixed height of your combobox.

If this doesn't help then please share all your code so I can do some testing in a sandbox.