# In LWC, Modal Dialog, I have a date field but its values are hidden because of the footer

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a modal dialog box on an object record page, when I load the page it renders. I have a date field in the modal dialog and the drop down of it is hidden under the footer. I have tried max-height, vertical-align, width and dropdown-alignment = bottom-left, but could not fix the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My trials

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange! Have you taken a look at these discussions yet? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331451 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275598

Comment: Hi Srilekha, Welcome to SFSE! Please edit your question and update with your research so far and paste the code so we can understand better the issue.

Comment: You need to share some code for us to replicate this.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` style for date lightning-input element or class name `slds-scrollable_none`

```
<lightning-input
    type="date"
    class="slds-scrollable_none"
></lightning-input>
```