# Combobox drop-down list out of container

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, lightning-combobox

I am using a combobox inside a modal and I have a problem.
You see,  when I want to pick a value for the combobox, the dropdown list is shown under it, inside the modal container. And because the modal is small, the user has to scroll inside the modal to pick their value. Very unpractical.

I was wondering if there was any way that the picklist would show "above" the container, in order to see the values without making the modal bigger or having to scroll inside it. I read the documentation on the component but

See the playground below to understand what I mean. Just click on the button to show the modal, and try to select a value for the combobox.

[Playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Kegsg9OrDSsZjTItqPM2?sv=1&pm=1)

Notice that it's even unusable if you add dropdown-alignment="bottom-left" to the combobox tag.

In any case, thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicate to
[Styling lightning:combobox drop down to not hide inside modal and extend modal length?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231397/styling-lightningcombobox-drop-down-to-not-hide-inside-modal-and-extend-modal-l/231486#231486)

try using this in your CSS file.

```
:host .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Comment: Apparently I had a weird way to phrase it since I didn't find that post, thank you for plugging it in.

You also need to mark the combobox as `position: absolute`