# How to improve the user experience for picklists in a lightning-record-edit-form in a modal?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, modal

I have a `lightning-record-edit-form` allowing the edit of 3 `lightning-input-field`s displayed in a [modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/).

The third field is a picklist:

[image: modal]

so when clicked on the options get clipped and the user has to understand that they must scroll to see all the options:

[image: modal clicked on]

I was thinking of re-sizing when the picklist is opened but neither of these events appear to be generated:

```
lightning-input-field onclick={handleClick} onopen={handleOpen} ...
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the user experience for this case?

(What I've done to date is added some padding below the picklist so the picklist opening is more obvious but that isn't an elegant solution.)

Comment: can refer to this, to apply CSS in LWC as per below link [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231397/styling-lightningcombobox-drop-down-to-not-hide-inside-modal-and-extend-modal-l](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231397/styling-lightningcombobox-drop-down-to-not-hide-inside-modal-and-extend-modal-l)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naveen's link solved this for me in that adding `style="overflow: initial;"` here:

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" style="overflow: initial;">
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Title"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Description"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="acl__Type__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>
```

allowed the picklist values to expand outside the modal:

[image: modal working]