# lightning combobox dropdown is hidden inside LightningModal

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox, lightning-modal

I'm building a lightning Combobox inside LightningModal but the dropdown list is hidden because the lightning modal container is not automatically extended as follows.

[image]

I already tried the solution provided in the following question
[Styling lightning:combobox drop down to not hide inside modal and extend modal length?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231397/styling-lightningcombobox-drop-down-to-not-hide-inside-modal-and-extend-modal-l/231486#231486)
but this solution seems to be not applied to Lightning Modal LWC.

My modal CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

I also tried to use custom styling by setting the class at lightning-modal-body as follows.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="項目の選択"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body class="my-modal-body"> 
            <c-display-flds  obj-name="govtech__shinsei__c" label="項目" placeholder="候補から選択" std-fld=true cst-fld=true mngd-fld=true onchange={handleChange}></c-display-flds>
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button class="slds-button_brand" label="完了" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
.my-modal-body {
overflow-y: initial;
}
```

Is there anyone have an idea to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix with changing the overflow doesn't work because you need to change the overflow of `slds-modal__content` which resides inside the `lightning-modal-body` component. It's not possible to do that because of how shadow DOM works. I think for now your best bet will be to create your own modal component using the SLDS styling and changing the overflow there. More on SLDS modals: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/

Comment: I got it thanks!